# How to persist the PeopleEditor value in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My requirement is based on the entered people editor value, i will show the details in the radgrid. here my problem is after clicked the button radgrid details and all coming perfect, but the people editor value is lost. but i nned to persist the people editor value. the same code i used in sharepoint 2010, but i have only the issue in sharepoint 2007, could anyone please help me to resolve this

Code:
 System.Collections.ArrayList entityArrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
                                        string[] vals = val.Split(';');
                                        foreach (string accntsVal in vals)
                                        {
                                            PickerEntity entity = new PickerEntity();
                                            entity.Key = accntsVal;
                                            entityArrayList.Add(entity);
                                        }
                                        peoplePicker.UpdateEntities(entityArrayList);

Thanks and Regards,
Santhanarasu.u

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 PeoplePicker.CommaSeparatedAccounts = string collection with comma separated value
```